# Load static files with django template tag

Tags: python, django, static, django-templates

I am trying to load image files saved in the static directory but this does not seem to do it

```
<div>
  {% thumbnail image.user.profile.photo "40" as in %}
     <a href="{{ image.user.get_absolute_url }}">
         <img src="{{ in.url }}" class="gametime"></a>

  {% endthumbnail %}
  <a href="{{ image.user.get_absolute_url }}" class="time">{{image.user.username }}  </a>    
</div>

<div id="details">
 {% thumbnail image.image "551" as im %}

     <a href="{{ image.image.url }}">
         <img src="{{ im.url }}" alt="{{ image.title }}"class="image-detail">
     </a>

 {% endthumbnail %}
</div>
```

I tried `<img src="{% static "rango.jpg" %}" alt="Picture of Rango">` and it displayed the rango.jpg image.

I think i need the `{% static %}` tag to accomplish this with image variable but still have not gotten it right.

Comment: You probably need to specify the *url pattern* to load the static files (or using a Django facility to do that)

Comment: Have you had a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/ - your approach with `{% static %}` is correct. Describe why it is not working for you.

Comment: Looks like your `image` is a model with an `image` `ImageField`. If that's the case they are not stored in the `static` dir but in `media`. And how to serve them is documented : for developement (dev server), read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development, for production they should be served by your front server cf https://timmyomahony.com/blog/static-vs-media-and-root-vs-path-in-django/

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yes you are right. image is an ImageField. Note: i am in production and deployment stage. so i think i need to reconfigure my settings. the above settings works fine in development but i am having trouble in production. any hints??

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers i thought i should add that my image model upload_to is set to /home/kingiyk/stylplus/static and my images are uploaded there.

Answer (score 0):

Did u setup the Static path in settings file.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```